ESP-IDF APSTA mode
I have a question about APSTA mode of esp32 device.
I try to initialize APSTA mode to make Access point active and have a possibility to provide credentials for STA later, but esp_wifi_connect function always returns ESP_OK even when credentials were set incorrectly.
I tried to verify if my custom function set_sta_creds really sets credentials and indeed they are present, so I assume credentials for STA interface were set correctly, but esp_wifi_connect function in any case returns ESP_OK, for example if I input wrong credentials then it returns ESP_OK instead of ESP_ERR_WIFI_CONN . I would appreciate any help, thanks.
I try to start APSTA mode like this:
esp_err_t WiFi::start_softap_sta(const char *ap_pass) 
{
    if (m_started) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to start AP-STA : wifi module should be reset");
        return ESP_FAIL;
    }

    if (!ap_pass || strlen(ap_pass) == 0 || strlen(ap_pass) >
                sizeof(((wifi_config_t*)0)->ap.password) / sizeof(uint8_t)
                || strlen(ap_pass) < 8) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to start AP-STA : invalid password");
        return ESP_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
    }

    ESP_LOGI(LTAG, "Starting AP-STA");

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_lock);

    m_netif_obj_ap = esp_netif_create_default_wifi_ap();
    if (!m_netif_obj_ap) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to create default netif wifi ap");
        return ESP_FAIL;
    }

    esp_err_t ret = esp_netif_dhcps_stop(m_netif_obj_ap);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to stop DHCP server : %s", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        stop_wifi();
        return ret;
    }

    esp_netif_ip_info_t ip;
    memset(&ip, 0 , sizeof(esp_netif_ip_info_t));
    ip.ip.addr = esp_ip4addr_aton(SOFTAP_LL_IP);
    ip.netmask.addr = esp_ip4addr_aton(SOFTAP_LL_NETMASK);

    ret = esp_netif_set_ip_info(m_netif_obj_ap, &ip);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to set ip info : %s", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        stop_wifi();
        return ret;
    }

    ret = esp_netif_dhcps_start(m_netif_obj_ap);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to start DHCP server : %s",
                    esp_err_to_name(ret));
        stop_wifi();
        return ret;
    }

    ret = esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to set AP-STA WiFi mode : %s",
                    esp_err_to_name(ret));
        stop_wifi();
        return ret;
    }

    wifi_config_t ap_conf;
    memset(&ap_conf, 0, sizeof(ap_conf));
    ap_conf.ap.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK;
    ap_conf.ap.max_connection = AP_MAX_CONNECTION;

    strncpy((char *)ap_conf.ap.password, ap_pass, strlen(ap_pass));

    std::string mac = get_mac();
    if (mac.empty()) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed t start AP-STA : failed to get MAC");
        stop_wifi();
        return ESP_FAIL;
    }

    snprintf((char*)ap_conf.ap.ssid, sizeof(ap_conf.ap.ssid),
            SSID_AP "%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
            mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);

    ret = esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_AP, &ap_conf);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to set configuration for AP-STA : %s",
                    esp_err_to_name(ret));
        stop_wifi();
        return ret;
    }

    ret = esp_wifi_start();
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to start WiFi module : %s",
                    esp_err_to_name(ret));
        stop_wifi();
        return ret;
    }

    m_started = true;

    return ret;
}

Also, I have the following function which connects to the STA while being in the APSTA mode.
esp_err_t WiFi::connect_softap_sta(const char *ssid, const char *pass) 
{
    esp_err_t ret = ESP_OK;

    if (ssid) {
        get_sta_creds(m_backup_ssid, m_backup_pass);

        ret = set_sta_creds(ssid, pass);
        if (ESP_OK != ret) {
            stop_wifi();
            return ret;
        }
    }

    ret = esp_wifi_connect();
    ESP_LOGI(LTAG, "INFORMATION");
    ESP_LOGI(LTAG, "%s", esp_err_to_name(ret));
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGE(LTAG, "Failed to connect WiFi module : %s",
                    esp_err_to_name(ret));
        stop_wifi();
        return ret;
    }

    return ret;
}

